# how to remove <object> video tag in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, object, video

my code like this:

```
<div id="player">
    <object width='100%' height='600' classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
        <param name='url' value='Video/3.mp4'/>
        <param name='ShowControls' value='-1' />
        <param name='ShowDisplay' value='-1' />   
        <param name='ShowStatusBar' value='-1' />
        <param name='stretchToFit' value='0' />
        <param name='uiMode' value='none' />  
    </object>
</div>
```

i use `$("#player object").remove()` to remove the object tag , actually the object tag was removed, but the video is also playing in page , even if `$("#player").remove()`.

what can i do to remove the playing video with object tag??

Comment: Your syntax is basically fine.

Do you have multiple tags in your page with id="player"? An id must be unique or you will most likely delete the wrong element!

Comment: there is only one object in my page ..0.0

Comment: You could also use $("#player").html("") to remove its contents but this would only work if the object tag is the only element inside your <div id="player">. Otherwise I am not certain what you are doing wrong, this works perfect for me, as you can see in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9AEY6/

Answer (score 2):

Hiding the object before removing the node will reset it, as a consequence it will stop the video.

```
$("#player object").hide().remove();
```

Comment: the video is also in page , keep playing but there is no <object> elem in <div id="player">

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
$("#player object").hide();
$("#player object").remove()
```

Comment: the elem was removed , but when i use $("#player object").show() , the video appear again.

Comment: So you can try a combination,var videoPlayer = $("#player object")[0];
videoPlayer.pause();$(videoPlayer).remove();$("#player object").hide();
$("#player object").remove();

Answer (score 0):

If video is still playing, then stop/pause it before removing.

```
var videoPlayer = $("#player object")[0]; // DOMElement, not jQuery object

// Stop video/audio
videoPlayer.pause(); 

// Remove from page using jQuery library
$(videoPlayer).remove();
```

Using JavaScript to control the HTML5 video player: [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

Comment: it doesn't work... after i  use in you way , the video was stopped , and the object elem was removed , but there is a black area or a video area also in the page and there is no children in "player" div .

Comment: @Maxpan my solution removes only player object, not div element. if you want to remove div#player, then you can change in my code `$(videoPlayer).remove();` to `$('#player').remove()`

Comment: after $(videoPlayer).remove() , but the video is also in page and playing , is there any other ways to solve it? thx all the same

Comment: I think you can try to hide it via `$(videoPlayer).hide()` before removing.